# Informatica Parameter File

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Whenever I use the `-lpf` parameter with the `pmcmd` command, the workflow runs perfectly fine but when I add the same path in the Parameter FileName under **Workflow 'Properties'** and try to execute the workflow from the Workflow Manager, I get an error saying that parameter file is not found.

Now, the path which I am giving for `'-lpf'` is :

```
/apps/config/informatica/param.txt.
```

I don't understand why it works when I am overriding the parameter file name, whereas it doesn't work when I add it in the workflow properties (the file is not found).

By default, is any Informatica *Environment variable* set which needs to be changed and what's the *default path* of the parameter file on server and can this be changed?

Comment: The above path looks like a relative path. Can you make sure the above is not the relative path. In case if it is a relative path, try giving the full path (from root directory) in the workflow properties

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the log file?

Assuming I did understand this:

when you run the workflow with the parameter file `-lpf` that has this path:

```
/apps/config/informatica/param.txt
```

it does work, instead when you run it manually does not.

it could be so simply that manually you have to put instead of the extended path the string  `$PMSourceFileDir\`  in the  Source file Directory  or to put it better: `Source file Directory = $PMSourceFileDir\`.

That because `$PMSourceFileDir` refer to the Informatica server initialization, as  it is a server variable.

Instead with a parameter file usually is used to override that "deafult" path.